# Does the Catholic Church have an official definition of Easter/Paschal Season?

Tags: catholicism, communion, easter, liturgical-calendar

One of the precepts of the Catholic Church says :"You shall humbly receive your Creator in Holy Communion at least during the Easter season." At some places, the words **Paschal Season** replace the phrase for the **Easter Season**. There appears to be an absence of uniformity in the definition of the said  Season. I wish to know if the Catholic Church has an official definition of Easter/Paschal  Season. Does it cover the Feast of Corpus Christi, which is most closely associated with the Holy Communion, and which falls on the Sunday immediately following the Feast of the Holy Trinity?

Comment: Is there  any linked evidence of an **”absence of uniformity in the definition of the said Season”** that you are talking about that you can source into your question?

Comment: The Feast of Corpus Christi is on the Thursday following the Feast of the Most Holy Trinity. In the Ordinary Form, it is merely transferred to the following Sunday!

Answer (score 0):

**Does the Catholic Church have an official definition of Easter/Paschal Season?**

The **Catholic Encyclopedia** explains it quite easily as follows:

> The fifty days from Easter Sunday to Pentecost are called by the older liturgists "Quinquagesima paschalis" or "Quin. laetitiae". - [Paschal Tide](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/11516a.htm)

Even **Wikipedia** agrees with this!

> Eastertide is the period of 50 days, spanning from Easter Sunday to Pentecost Sunday. It is celebrated as a single joyful feast, called the "great Lord's Day". Each Sunday of the season is treated as a Sunday of Easter. In some traditions, Easter Sunday is the first Sunday of Eastertide and the following Sunday (Low Sunday) is the second Sunday of Eastertide and so on; in other traditions, following the Sunday of the Resurrection, they are named Second Sunday of Easter, Third Sunday of Easter, etc. up to the Seventh Sunday of Easter, concluding with Pentecost Sunday. [Eastertide](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastertide)